# How to get a button to click other buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I having some trouble figuring this problem out where I have one button which does a mass clicking of other buttons on a page. Though the issue is I don't want to activate all the buttons all at once and basically time them out until the other buttons finish their actions.

```
Page.MassCheckStats = function(){
        $('[data-field="button_update_stats"]').each(function(){
            $(this).click();
        });
    }
```

How can I get the above code to click 3 buttons at a time before going on to the other buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive timeouts like this:

(sorry, i forgot it was three buttons at a time);

```
Page.MassCheckStats = function(button){
    var button = typeof button == 'undefined'?$('[data-field="button_update_stats"]')[0] : button;
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       $(button).click();
       if($(button).next().length == 0) return;
       button = $(button).next();
    }
    setTimeout(function(){             
       Page.MassCheckStats($(button));
    }, 1000);
}
```

where 1000 = 1000 miliseconds = 1 second

and here's the fiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/andrepadez/cR4tP/2/

the firs line inside the function is a trenary operator. it means that if you do not pass any parameter calling the function (the first time it is called), `typeof button == 'undefined'`, so it will assign to `var button` the first element selected by the jQuery selector - `$('[data-field="button_update_stats"]')[0]`. When i call it again from the timeouts, i am passing the current `$(button).next()` so it will assume what was passed in the parameter.

Comment: Hmm I clicked the click all and nothing happened.

Comment: wait nm it works now. Looks like this is exactly what I wanted :D thanks for your effort in teaching me this.

Comment: Actually just for learning purposes what does this part actually do: var button = typeof button == 'undefined'?$('[data-field="button_update_stats"]')[0] : button;

Answer (score 2):

instead of worrying about the buttons you should just call the functions assigned to each of the buttons click events

or if its the case of a certain button needing to do what the other three buttons do first, its function should contain those 3 functions

Comment: that is correct, but there are a lot of situations those functions are anonymous functions, and you really need to trigger the event...

Comment: Yeah, that's why tam's answer wouldn't of helped me in my situation since my functions are anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds incredibly hacky, but perhaps you could attach yet another click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $buttons = $('[data-field="button_update_stats"]');

    // attach your original events here

    for( var i = 0; i < $buttons.length-1; i++ ) {
        $button = $($buttons.get(i));
        $button.click(function(){$($buttons.get(i+1)).click();});
    }
}


// to start the chain
$($('[data-field="button_update_stats"]').get(0).click();
```

This code is completely ad-hoc and wasn't tested